# find the value of key in serialized array

Tags: php

I am new to this and I think question is also too stupid. But please help me. I have an `serialized array` as follow

```
a:1:{s:2:"to";s:21:"ucerturohit@gmail.com";}
```

this is a simple array of `{'to'=>'xxxxx'}`

now i want to print the value of key `to` without using `unserialize()`. please tell me
how can I do this ?

Comment: why would you not want to use `unserialize()`? Some guy told you it's not efficient?

Comment: Of course it would be possible with some string parsing, but why not take `unserialize` instead?

Comment: I don't get it why not using a function that's solely purpose is to do what you need? :-)

Comment: This isnt a real question I think, I mean wtf?

Comment: no thats not the matter. i just wanted to know that is there any other method to solve this problem? and please can any one tell that is there any difference between serialized array and Dictionary data structure

Comment: I can name several methods, which is probably hardly as efficient as `unserialize` and prone to error.

Comment: @RohitashvSinghal serialized is usually used to convert `php` array / object into a string representation, useful when you want to store it, for instance, in a mysql database, or cookie, or places where it's otherwise impossible / insensible to store a PHP native representation. Dictionary is another story altogether, asking the difference between them is like asking difference between an apple and a cat.

Comment: Well first a dictionary would be an object in PHP whereas this is a serialised string of varaibles, much like JSON. The two are not comparable. A dictionary is basically (in most base terms) a assoc array.

Comment: and guys 
please can any one tell me that is there any difference in `serialized array ` and `Dictionary Data Structure`

Comment: is there any reference of Dictionary in php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php arrays can be dictionaries in PHP, read the manual

Comment: So serialized arrays are strings for normalised storing whereas dictionaries are objects in PHP, one is for outside PHP the other is for inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to always get the key of the first element of the array, you could use something like this.

```
$array = array("a" => "b", "c" => array("d" => "e"));
$s     = serialize($array);

preg_match("/\{(.+)\}/", $s, $matches);

$_tmp     = explode(";",$matches[1]);
$_tmp_key = explode(":", current($_tmp));

return end($_tmp_key);
```

However, this will only work for the scenario above, and re-writing it to fit any case would be a waste of time. I would try an find a workaround to use unserialize instead.